# Create plot in matplotlib with appropriately sized axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the figure below, x-axis goes upto 54 and y-axis upto 8. However, the size of both is same. I would like to make the figure proportionate. I.e. x-axis should be longer than y-axis by a ratio of 54/8. Any suggestions?

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0,54)
plt.ylim(0,8)
#plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following line:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0,54)
plt.ylim(0,8)
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]